# How can I handle connection timeout and client timeout differently in retrofit with okhttp3

Tags: java, retrofit, socket-timeout-exception

I'm working on a instant message REST client library which communicate with a REST server belongs to 3rd party (there's no way I can touch the code or logic at server side) using retrofit v2.1.0.

For some reason I keep receiving java.net.SocketTimeoutException when calling the interface synchronically.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:212) ~[okio-1.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:288) ~[okio-1.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:242) ~[okio-1.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:325) ~[okio-1.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:314) ~[okio-1.8.0.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:210) ~[okio-1.8.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:184) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:125) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:775) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:86) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:760) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:613) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:244) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57) ~[okhttp-3.3.0.jar:?]
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174) ~[retrofit-2.1.0.jar:?]
```

By looking into the stack trace, I find out it's a client read timeout not a connection timeout, the server actually received my request, backend logic has been executed correctly, but my client failed to read the response from the server.

If I keep retrying, the server will receive duplicate request which might lead to sending duplicate messages to another client. there's serious consequences if I drop the client read timeout exception, but as a library it would be better if I can notify the users of my library that this exception actually happened, and they can choose to ignore or take other necessary actions.

If I swallow the SocketTimeoutException, and it is actually a connection timeout, the server might never received my request, I will lost a message from another client.

Any idea how I can achieve the goal that determine the SocketTimeoutException I got is a client read timeout or a connection timeout, and only retry on connection timeout?

**Update 1**

The code I use to create okhttp client and retrofit service:

```
public SampleApi createSampleService() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(clientBuilder.build())
            .build()
            .create(SampleApi.class);
}
```

I set retryOnConnectionFailure to true here, will this prevent throwing connection timeout error because it will keep retrying until the connection is successful, so the only timeout error I can possibly get is client read timeout? I wondering how many times it will retry and what happens after that.

Comment: AFAIK, it is always clients time-out, the server will execute normally, but the execution time might be too long (longer than time-out) duration defined on the client side, so the client rise the exception, how much time the server consumes before sending the response? try to increase time-out on client

Comment: Thx for the reply. My setting is 30 seconds, for both connection timeout and client read timeout, when I construct the okhttp client. The server should response less than 1 sec, but sometime the network itself might not be reliable. That's a rare case, but I still ran into it. If it is like you said, it's always client timeout, I think I can just throw the exception instead of keep retrying and let my users decide what further actions need to be take.

Comment: i may want to clear this out, i meant it's mostly (read time-out) because you confirmed the request reached the server, but the response did not reach the client, however, a dummy (on the blind) retry is not wise, specially like in ur case, where a duplicate/unique issue exist, may i ask did you set the timeout ur self or left it as default, in case you did that, can you show the code you used? because 30 seconds should be inputed in milliseconds, which will be (30000)

Comment: You need to look into making your transactions *idempotent.*

Comment: @Yazan Don't worry about the time, The okhttp client builder is using connectTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) and also to set it, not millisecond. I will update my question and add the code I use.

Comment: have you tried calling the service from third party apps. like Postman? does it work OK ?

Comment: @EJP I can't. Like I said before, I'm build a client side library for an instant message app, the server is from a 3rd party which I can't touch and need to follow it's API definitions. Every time I POST to a specified interface will create a new resource at the backend and return the created result. That's definitely not idempotence. So I need to handle possible exceptions very carefully to avoid duplication.

Comment: @Yazan I'm using [Restlet Client - DHC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-dhc/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en) in Chrome, and yes it's working. Timeout is a rare case and really hard to reproduce.